# How to use redis with hash storage in laravel?

Tags: laravel, redis

I used the laravel's default Redis::set() function to store items, but I have 13k records and the memory usage is around 400mb. Now I'm looking for ways to reduce it. I noticed laravel stores data as string not as hash which is wasting resources.
How can I use Redis with hash through laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official [Laravel Redis Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/master/redis), it's said that

> The Redis facade supports dynamic methods, meaning you may call any Redis command on the facade and the command will be passed directly to Redis

So I guess you can use

```
Redis::hSet('h', 'key1', 'hello');
$value = Redis::hGet('h', 'key1');
```

But I really doubt that you will reduce drastically your memory usage, unless you have very long key name. 
Instead you can :

- If it's possible think about executing [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) on your keys
- You can also compress your key value : for example, if it's encoded in json, you can use [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) which claims to be 1/3 smaller and faster to encode/decode, otherwise you can gz compress your content like explains in this [post](http://labs.octivi.com/how-we-cut-down-memory-usage-by-82/)
- You can use a Redis memory profiler like [this one](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) to search for a potential problem

If you test, let us know your results, it can be interesting.

Comment: Thanks it works this way. I'll update this post with results

Comment: Ahh sorry, I solved the problem another way. I stored the data instead in DB, and used nodeJs workers to compile and cache the results.